# Appropriate HTTP status code for file upload

Tags: rest, validation, http, http-status-codes

My application allows file upload. As a restriction I want to restrict files with only certain extension (say pdf for example)

So in case a file with pdf extension is uploaded, I return `200/201 ok` status code to indicate the successful upload.

I am confused, what should I return for non-pdf files after reading multiple answers-

1. **400** - argument to return `400 bad request` is that request failed due to validation. Argument to not to use is sometime it also indicates syntactical error while making the request.
2. **415** - argument to return `415 Unsupported Media` is that file extension is not same. (Considering Media as file), but content type (multipart/form-data) matches and is supported.
3. **422** - Argument to use `422 unprocessable entity` is that server understands the content-type (multipart/form-data) but still can't process the request. But other though is, it can still process if the use case is only to upload the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MDN:

> ## 415 Unsupported Media Type
>
> The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format.
>
> The format problem might be due to the request's indicated Content-Type or Content-Encoding, or as a result of inspecting the data directly.

I think the last sentence specifically suggests that 415 is not strictly for unsupported `Content-Type` headers.